# Passing argument to controller in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am developing an application using Symfony 2 and Twig for templating. I would like to know how to pass an argument to an action from a form action. I write it this way:

```
 <form action="{{ path('AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle_Interpretatu') with {{Argument}}  }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="erreg">
```

But it is not correct. Why with is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the parameters to the second parameter of path:

```
path('AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle_Interpretatu', 
    { "key": "value", "another key": "another value" })
```

(linebreak added only for clarity).